# stop a nested if loop that is inside a switch method | Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, switch-statement

So my friends and I have boon working on an app for the past few days, only issue is that neither of us know JavaScript. It went well until this point. I have learned a bunch from googling but I just can not seem to solve this problem. So we have a drop down menu that calls a function,

```
select id="vg" class="dropdown" onchange="vgchosen.call(this, event)">
```

this brings us down to our function, titled vgchosen. in this function, there is a switch method that is there to help evaluate witch drop down menu option was picked.

```
function vgchosen(event) {
alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
var vgc = document.getElementById("vg").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("vg").options;


switch (y[vgc].text) {
case "Action":
    var actionvgc = [
    "You should play |Skyrim",
    "You should play |Killing Floor 2",
    "You Should play |Counter Strike Global Offensive",
    "You should play |Left 4 Dead",
    "You should play |House of the Dead",
    "You should play |Elite: Dangerous",
    "You should play |Middle Earth: Shadow of Mordor",
    "You should play |Crypt of the Necro Dancer",
    "You should play |The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt",
    "You should play |Dark Souls",
    ];
    setInterval(function() {
        var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * actionvgc.length);
        if (i == actionvgc.length) --i;
        $("#actionvgc").html(actionvgc[i]);
        }, 1 * 1000);
        break;


case "Shooter":
    var shootervgc = [
    "You should play |Skyri",
    "You should play |Killing Floor ",
    "You Should play |Counter Strike Global Offensiv",
    "You should play |Left 4 Dea",
    "You should play |House of the Dea",
    "You should play |Elite: Dangerou",
    "You should play |Middle Earth: Shadow of Mordo",
    "You should play |Crypt of the Necro Dance",
    "You should play |The Witcher 3: Wild Hun",
    "You should play |Dark Soul",
    ];
    setInterval(function() {
        var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * shootervgc.length);
        if (i == shootervgc.length) --i;
        $("#actionvgc").html(shootervgc[i]);
    }, 1 * 1000);
    break;
}
}
```

when you start the function with a option selection, everything works fine, you are givin a new game idea every second. The problem comes into place when you want to switch to a different option. If you pick shooter (the game difference is that all the last letters are missing) it will display both game ideas at once. How can I stop the first loop when a new loop is started?

EDIT: #actionvgc is where the text is displayed. That can be seen here

```
<div id="actionvgc">"Hello World! im FLi!"</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval()` function returns a value that identifies that particular timer. You can use `clearInterval()` later to stop it.

```
var timerId; // should probably be global

// ...

clearInterval(timerId); // clear prev timer
timerId = setInterval(function() { /* ... */ }, 1000);
```

Comment: i think i understand your answer, but how do i implement it?

Comment: @JohnGalt what do you mean? I put the code right there in the answer.

Comment: sorry, i was being dumb, got it! Thankyou so much! Life saver!

Comment: @JohnGalt Just keep a global variable and use it to store the timer id. Each time you start a new timer, clear the old one first. Nothing bad happens if the timer ID variable isn't set up first, so you don't need a `null` check or anything.